# Subtract 2 minutes from order date in Control-M

Tags: control-m

In Control-M, I have a job that's scheduled 2 minutes after a batch interval ends, e.g. August 13th, 2021 at 00:02 (local time).

I need to pull files from a server on the format "YYDDMMHHMM.zip" and for example "HHMM" could be 2350 (10-minute frequency); the order time for that job would be 23:52.

How do I subtract 2 minutes from the order date/time? And if the system is running in a local time zone, how would one additionally express that result in UTC time? That is, the files on the server are timestamped in UTC time.

Comment: Your request is tied to a solution. I suggest you to reinvent a new design according to the real challenges in production. First of all, think that, if there is any delay or advance of the batch production, your system will require a manual intervention since the execution is determined by the date and time in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

The date parameters in Control-M do not include minutes or seconds, %%$DATE will resolve the yyyymmdd value.

If you want yesterday's date (i.e. at 1 minute after New Day Processing you want the previous ODAT value) use the CALCDATE facility to subtract (or add) 'x' days.

If you really want minutes adding/subtracting then that is best done at Unix system level.

Control-M just takes the time/date from the local system time.

Comment: I have updated the question to add a little more context to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could user `"%%CALCDATE %%TIME -120"`, but it will calculate based on the control-m/server time.

Comment: The expression does not work according to the requirement because the %%CALCDATE function adds or subtracts days to a specific date. The TIME parameter sent will be interpreted by %%CALCDATE as a date and not as a time.